# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'views'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Hello I'm learning Django framework for Web applications

I'm trying to build basic blog from tutorial

and I'm stuck with the error:

```
AttributeError is telling me that  'function' object has no attribute 'views'.
```

I don't know where I have problem in my files so I will include here some code of my files.

**There is my urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
import WarblerTest


urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    (r'^$', WarblerTest.blog.views.index),
    url(
        r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html',
        WarblerTest.blog.views.view_post,
        name='view_blog_post'),
    url(
        r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html',
        WarblerTest.blog.views.view_category,
        name='view_blog_category'),
}
```

**There is my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Blog, Category
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404


def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:5]
    })


def view_post(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('view_post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)
    })


def view_category(request, slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('view_category.html', {
        'category': category,
        'posts': Blog.objects.filter(category=category)[:5]
    })
```

**There is my models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

# Create your models here.

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique = True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique = True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField(db_index = True,auto_now_add = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view-blog-post',None, {'slug' : self.slug})

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100,db_index = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 100,db_index = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

**And there is my tracback error**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03853B28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 2
26, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\run
server.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", li
ne 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", li
ne 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", li
ne 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 1
4, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 2
4, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 3
5, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 313
, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 3
5, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 306
, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_modul
e
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Tornike\Desktop\WarblerTest\WarblerTest\urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    (r'^$', WarblerTest.blog.views.index),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'views'
```

Comment: can you share the stack error pls

Comment: I think this is a issue of the urls.py, normaly i import the views directly through `from . import views` and then just call `views.view_post`

Comment: Yes, Richy is right. Remove `WarblerTest.blog.` before `views` in url, and update your import.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question, so that we don't need to guess what line is causing the problem. Your urlpatterns should be a list, `urlpatterns = [...]`, not a set `urlpatterns = {...}`. It looks like your `urls.py` is your main `urls.py`, not your `blog/urls.py`. In that case, you need to do `from blog import views`, instead of `from . import views` as @Richy suggested.

Comment: Updated my post you can check now traceback in my question.

Comment: Since you are using Python 3 you should use `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`. You are also using `permalink`, which is very old and obsolete. If you're new to Django, I'm worried that you are using a very old tutorial or book that is out of date. If you are learning Django in 2017, you should be using material that is written for at least Django 1.8, otherwise you'll hit problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main project urls.py, remove the `import WarblerTest` import and replace it with `from blogs import views`.

Then update your url patterns to use the `views` module that you imported. Note that `urlpatterns` should be a `list` (square brackets `[...]` not curly braces `{...}` as you have. Every item should be a `url(...)` rather than a tuple `(...)` to avoid problems in Django 1.10+.

```
from blogs import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', views.view_post, name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', views.view_category, name='view_blog_category'),
]
```